# Databricks Custom Domain (URL)

Tags: azure-databricks

Surprised to not see an option of setting a custom domain (URL) for Azure Databricks. It is always created as adb-{number}.{number}.azuredatabricks.net. Can I know the reason and if in future the custom domain will be available?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to customize on the Azure Databricks. If you need to have custom domain names, contact your Databricks representative (solution architect or customer success engineer) to discuss that request.